# Internet Explorer automation doesn't get all elements

Tags: javascript, html, vba, getelementsbytagname

I'm learning about VBA web automation. I have successfully logged in to other websites and pulled data from them, but I couldn't do the same thing for this specific website: [https://moodle.telt.unsw.edu.au/](https://moodle.telt.unsw.edu.au/login/index.php).

```
<html>
   <div>
      <div>
         <div>
            <section>
               <div>
                  <div>
                     <div>
                         <div>
                           <iframe>
                             <html>
                                <there are more tags under here and if you go far enough you'll reach the elements I want VBA to read. They are under <input> tag>
                           <div>
```

I want VBA to get the three login elements that fall under the second `<html>` tag that is under `<iframe>`: `id = "username"`, `id ="password"`, and `id = "submit"`. I tried `getelementbyid("")` but for some reason it couldn't find these elements. I then tried using this code that lists all the elements' tags.

```
Sub moodleautomation()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim website As String
    Dim elements As Object
    Dim element As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    website = "https://moodle.telt.unsw.edu.au/login/index.php"

    With IE

        .Visible = True
        .Navigate website

        Do While .busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

       'get all elements in the document
       Set elements = .document.getelementsbytagname("*")

       'find how many elements there are in the document
       MsgBox elements.Length

       'Display each element's tag name
       For Each element In elements
            MsgBox element.tagName
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

After running this code it shows me the tags until `<iframe>` tag then it ignores `<html>` tag and all the tags under it and goes directly to `div` tag. The problem is that the elements I want to read are inside the second `<html>` tag that my code ignored.

Is there a way to read those elements?

EDIT:

```
Sub moodleautomation()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim website As String
    Dim elements As Object
    Dim element As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    website = "https://moodle.telt.unsw.edu.au/login/index.php"

    With IE

        .Visible = True
        .Navigate website

        Do While .busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

       'get iframe elements in the document
       Set elements = .document.getelementsbytagname("iframe")

       'find how many iframe elements there are in the document
       MsgBox elements.Length

       'get the iframe document
       Set element = elements.contentDocument



    End With

End Sub
```

This code gives me an error message that says "Object doesn't support this property or method" on this line (Set element = elements.contentDocument)

Comment: contents of an iframe are a separate document - you'll need to read that separately

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I googled it and found that a solution to this problem is to use .document.getelementsbytagname("iframe").contentDocument but it somehow returned an error message.

Comment: can you somehow convey what the error message is, or do we have to guess?

Comment: "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: perhaps you need to `Set element = elements[0].contentDocument`

Comment: I tried    **Set element = elements(0).contentDocument** and    **Set element = elements.item(0).contentDocument** they both returned an error of "automation error"

Also, Set **element = elements.item(0).contentWindow.Document** returned an error of "Access is denied"